# How to get better performance in a minimalist conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, performance

I work with JavaScript but I always wonder this for all the languages.

Do I get better performance doing this:

```
var i = 0;
if(j < 0) 
{
   i = 1;
}
```

Or this?

```
var i;
if(j < 0) 
{
    i = 1;
}
else 
{
    i = 0;
}
```

With 50% chance to have `j < 0`

Comment: Did you try to benchmark?

Comment: I don't know what kind of high performance system you're trying to build but I'm 100% sure you're focusing on the wrong problems. Performance wise it doesn't matter for you.

Comment: Just a suggestion though it is not an answer why not ternary operator

`i = (j < 0) ? 1 :0;`

Comment: The ternary operator (preferably on the same statement than `var`) would be the good thing to use. Because it's simpler. And because performance doesn't matter here.

Comment: @user1671639 Though it may *look* more efficient to read and write, it might not actually be more efficient to execute. Benchmarks will determine.

Comment: Why don't you try it on `jsperf`?

Comment: @Andy: backticks are for marking up code. You want [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: For better clarity in your code use ternary operation `var i = j < 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @dystroy I tried to do some test cases where I got this http://jsperf.com/test-case-of-if-else .  Seems using ternary operator is faster in chrome.  Not sure about test case, please correct me if I meant something wrong.

Comment: @Boaz I tried some test cases here http://jsperf.com/test-case-of-if-else it seems using ternary has greater performance than regular if.else statement.   Not sure about test case, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user1671639 I wasn't implying that the ternary operator is slower, only that appearances in such matters may be misleading. The benchmarks seem to indicate that is not the case here. Though notice that as many have suggested, this is probably a classic case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will depend on the implementation of javascript engine, which, at least if you write your code for the Web, is out of your control.

One browser might be faster with first version of the code, the other with the second version. And tomorrow it might change.

**Do not optimize things like this unless you have pinned down this one line of code as a bottleneck of your task.**

You might want to read [when to optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

You will be better of to write readable and well designed code, and let the browser vendors wory about machine level optimisations.

The things you should optimize are algorithms, and not language specific constructions.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your code makes much of a difference. Depends on the JS engine of course but todays engines are pretty advanced and optimize code very well(especially V8 on chrome and node.js).

Benchmark it. You can use simple `console.time('label'); console.timeEnd('label')` at least in Chrome.

In my opinion your code looks ugly and like a bloat. A lot of space is consumed with no content. I would prefer this approach as it reads much faster and you should care about **readability** as much as **performance**:

```
var i;    
if(j < 0) {
    i = 1;
} else {
    i = 0;
}
```

Also you have an access to ternary operator:

```
var i = j < 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

which is readable if you do not nest it. Again - performance wise all of them are equal and will differt by maybe a millisecond or two so you should not care about performance in such simple cases. Care about readability :)

Also performance will depend on your j value. If optimizer will see that you set `j to 1`. It will short-circuit the whole code and simply set `i = 0`. IMHO in such simple cases it's not useful to spend time to search for improvement except for readability :).